# ML models can only be used for making future predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I'm aware that ML models are used to make future prediction but can they also be used for making predictions in the past?

I've a model that predicts the accident prone zones for a given location and given date and time. The model has been developed by studying previous 2 years data (2020 and 2021). I've few datasets that I am required to predict on, which are in the year 2019. This is required to verify if the predictions actually tally.

Now, would it be feasible to use this ML model to test on the dataset for the year 2019?

I'm using sklearn and the model used is Random forest.

Comment: Generally yes, since your model doesn't care for the date. The model is basically just a mapping between input and output without taking the date in regard. You do have to consider that accident prone zones could have been different in the past, so your model might be off in that sense if you test on the 2019 data.

Comment: This is a statistics question for stats stackexchange, not a programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically it is possible. It doesn't matter which direction you go. e.g. if a trend is seen to increase in the future, this means the trend is probably decreasing in the past. So for the model it doesn't matter much - it is going to predict a decrease (for example). However, how relevant is your prediction, it is something to sought for.